# Mac Pro will not go to 2560 x 1600 Display Resolution

Tags: mac, display

I can't get my new 30" Apple Cinema Display to show a 2560 x 1600 resolution.  I have a Mac Pro 1,1.  I've tried resetting `pram` and changing graphic card ports.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the original Geforce 7300 GT in there, it can support 2560 x 1600 over a dual-link DVI cable only - & only from one of the two sockets; so the first thing I'd check would be the cable/socket config.

From [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/specs/mac-pro-quad-3.0-specs.html)...

> The NVIDIA GeForce 7300 GT with 256 MB of GDDR2 SDRAM is installed in
>   a "double-wide" 16-lane PCI Express slot. It has one single-link DVI
>   port and one dual-link DVI port. Other graphics card options included
>   the 512 MB ATI Radeon X1900 XT and the 512 MB NVIDIA Quadro FX 4500,
>   Stereo 3D with two dual-link DVI ports.
>
> The NVIDIA GeForce 7300 GT is capable of supporting "digital
>   resolutions up to 1920 by 1200" pixels, the dual-link DVI port
>   supports "up to 2560 by 1600 pixels". It also supports analog
>   resolutions "up to 2048 by 1536".

Comment: I have two ports.  One leaves the monitor idle and the other supports the monitor in low resolution.  The cable is the original Apple cable on the Cinema Display.  Is there something else physically that I need to do (i.e. Open the case and move the graphics card to the other port) ?

Comment: Shouldn't be, afaik. The card should be in the bottom slot on most Mac Pros [though I've never owned a 1,1 I doubt that would have changed] although Everymac claims that machine can run 4 Graphics cards, so maybe they're all the same. I'd be tempted to test a different cable, or get a repair shop to check that one, just to be certain. There's a reasonable possibility that only one link is working.

Comment: cables and recepticals are all dual link dvis.  the cable was just working on my step son's computer.

Comment: Did you check cable & monitor together on that machine, or at least using another monitor that *requires* dual link? If not, then we still haven't eliminated anything. The cable, monitor, or graphics card itself may be misbehaving. Short of swapping things out one by one, testing against known-good, or getting a repair shop to test it, I'm afraid I have no other simple 'user method' to test; unless the Apple Hardware test might be able to check it.

Comment: okay, thanks so much.  I reset the cable three times into the alternate port and the resolution has gone to 2560 x 1600!  Thank you for the help~

Comment: ahh... grubby connection possibly, fixed by repeated inserts. We may never know for sure - glad you got it going :)